# How to get code of different version of a web application build on tfs 2008 server

Tags: tfs, tfs-2008

I have been created a web project on tfs server and set a build for this application, which builds the application daily. I want to give a specific version of build to testing team, but if that version was build successfully before two or three days, how can I get the source code of that particular build which was build successfully a few days before.

Comment: this is more appropriate to our sister site, Stack Overflow.  you will need to register an account there with the same OpenID in order to regain ownership of the question.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you'll need to roll back to the Changeset you are looking for.  This artcile will explain how to do that.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms194956(VS.80).aspx